# Chat with an expert?

Tags: support, chat, stackexchange, fun

What is this?

[image]

[image]

The upper small banner appeard twice in the last few days and disappears when clicking not now and can’t be found again. The lower window opens if i click “chat with an expert” and it was both times “An Expert“ an the same Avatar.

Is this a new feature, a bug or a hack?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert

Comment: StackExchange April fools [Eliza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA)

Comment: Get it … but it was odd cause it appeared a few days ago the first time, I belief :-/

Comment: Nerds trying to be funny but usual outcome... appeared again as we speak.

Comment: @Tobi: I think it appeared around the beginning of 1 April in Newzealand, but I can't be sure.